# Database - Superkeys

Tags: sql, database

I am currently trying to study about databases and came across the concept of superkeys, which confuse me a little bit, could someone help define what a superkey actually is? As far as my understanding goes a superkey is the column in a table which makes the tuple unique, is that right?

Lets say I have three tables, CUSTOMER, ACCOUNT and TRANSACTION
And they each looked something like the tables below:

[image]

Would 'cid' be the superkey for CUSTOMER? or are there more than one?
Which superkey violates the tables? As far as I understand {num, type, desc} violates ACCOUNT as there is no distinct column in the table, is that correct?
How about TRANSACTION?

kindest regards,

KRS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A superkey is (simplistically) a set of attributes (columns) for which there are no duplicates. In other words, it's the set of columns required for a unique key.

In the customer table, the *minimal* superkey would be `cid`.

It cannot be `name` because there are two people called Jill, and it cannot be `phone` because Jack and one Jill are obviously shacking up together in the same house.

In the transaction table, the minimal superkey would most likely be `cid+num+time`, assuming you were not allowed more than one transaction per second.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 

Just a few quick questions. Are superkeys and minimal superkeys the same thing? Also, can a relation have more than one superkey? so for example or TRANSACTION the superkeys would be {cid+type+time} and {num+type+time} and {cid+time}

Comment: @Zambot, no, a minimal superkey is the minimum collection of columns that will make a superkey. Any combination that includes a minimal superkey is, by definition, a superkey itself. So both `cid` and `cid+name` are superkeys since they _both_ have no possibility of duplicates. That also answers your second question, there can be more than one superkey in a relation. Whether those _particular_ examples are superkeys depends on the restrictions placed on the data, eg, if each customer is allowed five transactions per time unit on the same type, `cid+type+time` is not a superkey.